# Do you get two actions when you return from space with Starbuck?

Tags: battlestar-galactica

In Battlestar Galactica, "Starbuck" has a special ability that when she starts her turn in space, she gets two actions instead of one. This makes sense because as a snazzy pilot, she can out-manuever everyone.

However, what happens if she decides to move back into the Galactica?

More specifically, does she get two actions inside the Galactica if she started her turn in space and discarded a card to go back into the Galactica?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, she does. The rule is stated quite clearly, no need to second-guess it. Maybe she's on such a rush from piloting that for the rest of the turn she can still get stuff done, even on Galactica.

Comment: I'm second guessing because that's (a) not thematic and (b) quite powerful, as it allows the character to, for example, do an action and then XO another player to do two actions, which is how we use it.

Comment: It is quite powerful, definitely motivation to keep her in a viper! Also gives a cylon Starbuck some good options for a nasty reveal.

Comment: It is in the FAQ Q: If Starbuck starts her turn piloting a viper, does she receive
two actions if she moves to Galactica or Colonial 1?
A: Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, she can move to Colonial One or Galactica and use two actions if she started her turn in a viper. The [FAQ](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/Battlestar_Galactica/bsg_FAQ_2_hi-res.pdf) states this clearly. Remember that the player needs to discard one skill card to move from the viper to the Colonial One or Galactica.